# Increase maximum zoom *out* of MKMapView in iPhone/iPad

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, mkmapview, zooming

I'm having trouble getting an `MKMapView` to zoom far enough out (I need to see every continent i.e. the entire world in one `MKMapView`) on the iPhone/iPad. The maximum "out" zoom seems to be hard limited. Is there a known way to increase or remove this limit?

Answer (score 2):

Refer the following link, http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/set-the-zoom-level-of-an-mkmapview/ and use like,

```
[mapView setCenterCoordinate:myCoord zoomLevel:24 animated:YES];
```

this will allow you to show the whole map on `MKMapView` according to the concept (http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/mkmapview-and-zoom-levels-a-visual-guide/)

Comment: Thank Tony, but MKMapView doesn't have zoomLevels on the iPhone :( People have written classes that simulate it, but the code didn't work for me (and I don't think it would solve my problem anyway because gesture zooming out to maximum is likewise locked on the phone).

Answer (score 1):

The world map is square. If your mapview is not square you'll be stuck at the point where the top and bottom have hit the edge of the world map.

Comment: Ah, so the view area must be square to allow all of the world map to be seen? Thanks, I'll try that.

Comment: Actually... that doesn't work. Irrespective of the shape of the mapview area, the map just won't zoom out to show everything :(